# How to render template in Odoo 16

Tags: templates, odoo, render, odoo-16

I'm working in Odoo 16, I have created a scheduled action and template.

How can I render the template in the scheduled action?

I have only two files: `views/.xml` and `model/.py`

I've tried the `render_template()` method but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Odoo version, it will be something like:

```
template = self.env['mail.template']._render_template(body, res_model, [res_id])
```